# Project apk crashing on real world device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I have some problem with my android project! I have created a preferences intent and it works fine in the emulator. but when I transfer the project and launch the preferences through the menu key of the mobile, it stops working and closes! I want to know what is going on with it!

My device is : Xperia Mini Pro --> Running Android ICS 4.0.4

the code is,

Preference class :

```
package com.sliit.droidman.main;

import com.sliit.droidman.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class Prefs extends PreferenceActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
}
}
```

Preference xml file :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
 <EditTextPreference
    android:title="Edit text"
    android:key="name"
    android:summary="enter your name"
 ></EditTextPreference>
 <CheckBoxPreference
    android:title="Music"
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:key="checkbox"
    android:summary="check this box"
 ></CheckBoxPreference>
 <ListPreference
    android:title="list"
    android:key="list"
    android:summary="this is a list to choose from"
    android:entries="@array/list"
    android:entryValues="@array/lValues"
 ></ListPreference>
 </PreferenceScreen>
```

Place where the preferences is called into action :

```
 SharedPreferences getprefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    boolean music = getprefs.getBoolean("checkbox", true);
    if (music == true) {
        splashmp3.start();
    }
```

what Am I doing wrong here! I dont have any issue with the emulator! but the problem exists with the device! As I had a previous application developed in the same manner, I ran it in the device and it worked fine on the preferences. but this force closes. Do I have to give any permissions! O.o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was giving the error. it was an error where I create the prefs intent in a switch case. :) I have mistyped the class name. so I corrected it and now it works like magic!

```
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.about:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, About.class));
        break;
    case R.id.prefs:
        Intent prefs = new Intent("com.cdap.droidman.PREFS");
        startActivity(prefs);
        break;
    case R.id.exit:
        finish();
        break;
    }
```

Comment: it should be 

`Intent prefs = new Intent(this, prefs.class);`